# Getting latest products base on their category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get my latest products of each category in separate panel in my index page,

for this matter there are 3 tables involved `products` `admin_designs` and `categories`

## Logic

In my `admin_designs` table i will select categories and `base on my selected category` there will add `new panel` to my index page including `last 10` products in that category.

> So far I can get my categories products in index page in separate
>   panels BUT not as I wish.

## Problems

1. I'm not able to get categories title
2. I only get `1` product as result however I limited results for `10`
3. I want to get `title` value from `admin_designs` table instead of category title **if is provided only** but i can't find it in my query.

## codes

`controller`

```
    public function welcome() {
        //rest of the codes....

        //dynamic categories
        $category = DB::table('admin_designs')
                  ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'admin_designs.category_id')
                  ->join('products', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'products.category_id');
                  })
                  ->groupby('categories.id')
                  ->take(10)
                  ->get();
        return view('welcome', compact('category'));
}
```

my `blade` code

```
@foreach($category as $ki)
  // title of panel
  cat id: {{$ki->category_id}}  //return category id from products table (the best i could get instead of category title!)

  //panel data
  {{$ki->title}} // product title
@endforeach
```

**NOTE:** as you see in my controller i have `->take(10)` but my result only get `1` (I have enough products in each category so is not about that i don't have data)

## Screenshot

`this is actual results`

[image: screenshot1]

## UPDATE

`categories schema` I need title from this table.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('imageAlt')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_tags')->nullable();
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
        });
```

`Admin_designs schema` I need title from this table

```
Schema::create('admin_designs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('admin_designs', function($table) {
           $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
           $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
        });
```

`products schema` I need everything from this table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('imageOne');
            $table->string('imageTwo')->nullable();
            $table->text('short_description');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_tags')->nullable();
            $table->string('arrivalDays');
            $table->string('height')->nullable();
            $table->string('weight')->nullable();
            $table->string('lenght')->nullable();
            $table->string('width')->nullable();
            $table->string('sku');
            $table->string('stock');
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('subcategory_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('subcategory_id')->references('id')->on('subcategories');
        });
```

### Relations

`category.php`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
  public function admin_designs(){
     return $this->hasMany(AdminDesign::class);
  }
```

`admindesign.php`

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

`product.php`

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
```

## UPDATE 2

I decided to remove my `admin_designs` table and instead I added a column to my `categories` table and local scope to my category model. Now when I set my new column value to `1` that category products will show in homepage.

here is the query of that:

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->OfListed()->get();
```

**ISSUE:**

I need this query to get only last `10` products of my category and not more than that. How can I add that condition to it?

Comment: you have used grouped by with category id for the product so only one product will be allowed for one category id

Comment: because if i use `groupby('category_id`)` i get error :\

Comment: @SagarGautam this is the error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'category_id' in group statement is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `admin_designs` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `admin_designs`.`category_id` inner join `products` on `admin_designs`.`category_id` = `products`.`category_id` group by `category_id` limit 10)`

Comment: I'm sorry I've not mean that wait a minute

Comment: Can you add the details about the table columns of the joined data necessary in view

Comment: @SagarGautam I need `all columns in my products` table + `title in admin_designs` table and `title in categories` table.

Comment: And then max of 10 product in each category am I right ?

Comment: @SagarGautam right

Comment: @SagarGautam last thing i need to mention is: i tried to add `->latest()` before request for `10` products it gaves error as well. i don't know why.

Comment: Did you use relationship among category and product table ?

Comment: Please add the database table structure for the above three tables please

Comment: @SagarGautam yes i did, i will update

Comment: @SagarGautam updated my question fully.

Comment: Quite complex as per your requirement.

Comment: @SagarGautam so what you saying is that you're not able to help right?

Comment: I'll try my best

Comment: You need some nested for loops in the controller to pick up 10 product of each category but this is not the optimal solution I think performance might degrade.

Comment: see if i don't use categories in my query and just compare product cat id with admin_designs cat id i can get 10 products but the thing is then how to get category title?

Comment: somehow then $ki->category->title doesn't return category title

Comment: $ki->category->title this doesn't work because you are using query builder not eloquent

Comment: well I can't think of any other solution please help me if you can, thanks.

Comment: Just make use for loop to get data of each category then use this data in view

Comment: @SagarGautam Bro I found the solution (tiny issue) and updated my question please check it. thanks.

Comment: Okay have fun :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved

Comment: Congrats man you have solved :D

Comment: @SagarGautam thanks man, it solved partly, my method works just fine except i get all products of each category instead of last 10 only.

Comment: ooh that means you've not got exactly what you want :D

Comment: @SagarGautam yes, and you answerd good luck! :))

Comment: okay nice to see